# Retreive specific value from DB with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, database, pyodbc

I am trying to get a specific value from an SQL table with pyodbc in Python.
The table dbo.passes has 2 columns: `('user_name','password')` with values `('test','5555')`.
I have the following code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM [dbo].[passes] where user_name ='test'")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)

passw = input("enter pass ")
if passw == row: 
    print ("nice")
else:
    print ("wrong")
```

If my input is `5555` it does not match the "row" because it comes out as `('5555             ')`

How can I retrieve from the database only the value 5555 in this case, but not in a list format?

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: Password should not be stored clear in the database. It should be hashed, usually with sha-256.

Comment: I am using SSMS

Comment: It's a very simple project, no need to hash this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. SQL, by design, returns tuples. Access your list value in python, something like this:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT password FROM [dbo].[passes] where user_name ='test'")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)

passw = input("enter pass ")
if passw == row['password']: # Could also be row[0], idk you have to try
    print ("nice")
else:
    print ("wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

The row[0] suggestion worked, only slightly different:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT RTRIM (password) FROM [dbo].[passes] where user_name = 'test'")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)

sqlpass = row[0]
print (sqlpass)

passw = input("enter pass ")
if passw == sqlpass: 
    print ("nice")
else:
    print ("wrong")
```

The RTRIM is necessary since the field is a varchar(20) and the returned string is the stored string plus any amount of blank spaces to get to 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I retrieve from the database only the value 5555 in this case, but not in a list format?

pyodbc supports a [.fetchval()](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fetchval) method that returns a single scalar value:

```python
count = cursor.execute('select count(*) from users').fetchval()
```